# Number of times a iphone app installed

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iphone stuff. After deploying an application in iTunes is there a way to find out the number of iphone/ipod touch which has installed / uninstalled this application ?

During uninstall the user is asked to rate the application, how to get that information with a developer license credentials ?

Comment: You can get installs (downloads) from your sales figures on a daily basis in iTunesConnect.  They get deleted after 7 days

Comment: Can we get this information programaticaly ? through some webservice call ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple tells you the number of sales (and the number of upgrades) in [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/). What they don't tell you is how many people have uninstalled your application or, more importantly, how many people are still using it *n* days after installing it.

You may be able to get this information (and more) using one of the third party analytic tools such as [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/), although Apple has recently started to object to service like them. Another option would be to gather the same kind of information on your own server.

It would be really nice if Apple provided better information but, unfortunately, they don't at the moment.

Comment: stephen one more query, during uninstall user gets a screen where he/she can rate the application. Where will this information stored ? will it be available at itunesconnect ?

Comment: @thndrkiss Unfortunately not. You can see the reviews for each country App Store in iTunes Connect but the only official way to see ratings is using iTunes (or the App Store on your handset). There are programs and services that "screen scrape" that kind of information but there's no API.

Comment: If they leave an actual review, it IS available in iTunesConnect, otherwise all you see is the star rating.  I use `PositionApp` to check my standings daily and http://www.appannie.com (which is free) as well

Answer (score 1):

All this data is provided through Apples iTunes connect site

https://itunesconnect.apple.com

Additionally you could subscribe to one of the support sites like

http://www.appfigures.com

which will give you nice graphs on sales etc

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at Flurry Analytic's. Not only will it tell you how many unique devices it has been installed on, but you can add events as well. So lets say your app has a "Featured Listings" area or something like that. Flurry will log how many times people enter into the "Featured" area. It will help track conversion rates...

Also shows you the navigation path the user took. So they click on , "search", then they click on "homes", then they clicked on "featured"... yada yada yada... it provides excellent information.

If your app uses Core Location you can even see a dot on a map as to where the user was when they did all of this.

http://www.flurry.com/

-LT

Answer (score 1):

The information provided by iTunes Connect is the number of downloads of your app. The ratings and reviews are actually not provided via iTunes Connect, but you can find it indirectly on the app store.

There are some services that aggregate all this information for you. A new one is [www.appannie.com](http://www.appannie.com) which shows you both downloads and ratings.

Answer (score 1):

For number of installed Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had. [image]